# Open cart price issue

Tags: e-commerce, opencart

Specification : e-Commerce - Opencart Version 1.5.2.1

---

**ISSUE :**

Present output in **Front end**

For example : Product#1 - Price: $89.10 (NO tax)

Where as Open cart - **Admin Panel**, I have assigned as,

Product#1 - Price: $99.00

---

There are no tax applied, no discount applied and no other special vouchers or anything but still there is a $9.9 of difference in the front end compared to the entry made in open cart admin panel.

**How I can fix open cart price issue?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Your administration -> System -> Settings go edit Your site, pick the **Options** tab and search for the *Taxes* part.

If You have the option **Display Prices With Tax:** checked as **No**, check **Yes** instead (or vice versa) and **Save**.

This should solve the problem.

Comment: The procedure that you have explained is to hide/ show "Ex Tax: $89.10" which is below "Price: $89.10". I haven't applied any deduction in the price of a product but still there is a deduction of $9.9. I am in a terrible need of help. I appreciate your effort Shadyyx.

Comment: So did You try it or not? You have probably o 10% tax set in Your system and OpenCart could erroneously subtract the 10% from the price if it is set to display prices without taxes even if You have not set any tax for the concrete product...

Comment: Yes, I have tried and the previous comment was the result. It's an option to hide or show "**Ex Tax: $89.10**" I have not added any tax or any other deductions as I have mentioned earlier.

Comment: Answer : The problem was due to module named "Zappo - Group Discounts" was hard coded in upload\system\library\customer.php.Go to open cart admin panel > System > website - edit > Option > text_account > Customer Group: drop down > select - Wholesale.If you choose "Wholesale" notice will be displayed in website front end so add error_reporting(0); at the top until you uninstall the configuration of "Zappo - Group Discounts" module.

Comment: @BannedfromSO So You solved the problem Yourself? So be carefull in the future what extensions You are using. It could happen that many extensions together could collide one with another and cause inunderstandable problems...